# Python: how to split a string by multiple strings

Tags: python, string, split

Given a string:

> str = "apple AND orange  OR banana"

I want to split it by "AND" or "OR". The expected result is

> ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']

Is any simple way for python to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: *please* don't use `str` as a variable name. `str` is a well-known builtin and you are asking for all kinds of trouble overriding it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use regex to split based on any combinations of uppercase letters with len 1 or more :

```
>>> tr = "apple AND orange OR banana"
>>> re.split(r'[A-Z]+',tr)
['apple ', ' orange ', ' banana']
```

But if you just want to split with `AND` or `OR` :

```
>>> re.split(r'AND|OR',tr)
['apple ', ' orange ', ' banana']
```

And for remove the spaces if you are sure that your sentence are contain distinc words you can do :

```
>>> re.split(r'[A-Z ]+',tr)
['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
```

If you have a `AND` or `OR` in leading or trailing of your string using split will create a empty string in result , for get ride of that you can loop over splited list and check for validation of items, but as a more elegant way you can use `re.findall` :
with `r'[^A-Z ]+'` as its pattern :

```
>>> tr = "AND apple AND orangeOR banana"
>>> re.split(r'\s?(?:AND|OR)\s?',tr)
['', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana']
>>> re.split(r'[A-Z ]+',tr)
['', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana']
>>> [i for i in re.split(r'[A-Z ]+',tr) if i]
['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
>>> re.findall(r'[^A-Z ]+',tr)
['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
```

Comment: Use `'\s+(AND|OR)\s+'` and the whitespace is gone, too ;-)

Comment: Your last code will fail if there is an OR or AND at the beginning or end of the string

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yea! i miss `?` but i fixed the answer! better!

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two ways to accomplish this:

```
In [230]: s = "apple AND orange OR banana"

In [231]: delims = ["AND", "OR"]

In [232]: for d in delims:
   .....:     s = s.replace(d, '-')
   .....:     

In [233]: s.split('-')
Out[233]: ['apple ', ' orange ', ' banana']
```

OR

```
In [234]: s = "apple AND orange OR banana"

In [235]: delims = ["AND", "OR"]

In [236]: for d in delims:
   .....:     s = s.replace(d, ' ')
   .....:     

In [237]: s.split()
Out[237]: ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
```

Comment: Besides using two `for` loops this is the cleanest way I could think of.

Comment: You'd need to find a delimiter that's not in hour string already. Which can be challenging.

Answer (score 2):

You can split and filter with a set:

```
s = "apple AND orange OR banana"

print([word for word in s.split() if word not in {"AND","OR"}])

['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `filter` and `re.split` like this:

```
my_list = list(filter(None, re.split("\s*(?:AND|OR)\s*", my_str)))
```

This will work even in the case that AND or OR is at the very beginning of your string. Also, you should be aware that `str` is a pretty terrible variable name since it is a built-in.

This gives the output:

```
['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
```